# customization of AMP-HTML

Tags: javascript, cookies, amp-html

In order to ensure compliance with the Cookie Law when using AMP, I need to be able to block the scripts that install cookies and activate them only once the user has given consent. I'm trying to achieve this on AMP-compliant pages, but I'm having the issues described below.

Upon reading the AMP documentation, I noticed that it is only possibile to insert scripts if the script type is set to “application/ld+json”.
The way we currently handle the blocking and re-activation of scripts once the cookie consent has been provided is to change the script type into plain/text in the page source, then switching it back via javascript only after the consent has been given.

How can we achieve this on an AMP-compliant page?
If it's not possibile insert custom script tags, can I create an “AMP-plugin” or a script accepted by the AMP system that makes me achieve the same?
Is it possible to prevent AMP activation at page load to then activate it with a specific trigger?

Also, we've noticed that the AMP js itself is installing cookies. Can the load of the AMP js also be subject to user consent to cookies?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you add some comments on what cookies you are trying to write? Is it something that one of the analytics vendors writes?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies might be troublesome either way. AMP sites are delivered via Google CDN - so they run on a google subdomain instead of your own domain. This is done by Google to further accelerate the render speed of the site.

So even if you could write a cookie, its scope would be the google subdomain, instead of your own domain.

There seem to be some work-arounds in context of the amp-analytics plugin:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/analytics/analytics_basics

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [cookie accept sample](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/amp-user-notification_with_server_endpoint/).
Hope this helps. Normaly it is okay to inform the user only that you use cookies.
If you want block cookie before loading the AMP you must handle it self by a script. Same whren user not accept.

Comment: _If you want block cookie before loading the AMP you must handle it self by a script. Same whren user not accept._
This could be a good idea but i tried that without good results.
Have you some example to show me?

Answer (score 1):

Cookie writing can be controlled by passing in `amp-user-notification-id` as described in https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/analytics-vars.md#clientid

The exact code that you need to use depends on what component is writing the cookies. Is it an analytics vendor or an ad or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your advice Avi.
I want to block all components that installs cookies: is it enough to specify in the html tag the attribute `data-consent-notification-id=“amp-user-notification-id`?I saw that this attribute is not accepted from all components (like the thirdpart ones and so on). How do I do it in this case?